# I changed the JENKINS_USER=root but it is still jenkins in ubuntu

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, supervisord

I used "apt install jenkins" installed jenkins and it is started successful. but when it build a item it throw a error as below:

```
+ whoami
jenkins
+ supervisorctl restart Zonr.RuifWu.WebApi
error: <class 'PermissionError'>, [Errno 13] Permission denied: file: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/xmlrpc.py line: 560
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

So I vi /etc/defualt/jenkins and modify the config

```
#JENKINS_USER=$NAME
#JENKINS_USER=$NAME
JENKINS_USER=root
JENKINS_GROUP=root
```

I execute the command "systemctl restart jenkins" and build the item again, it still show the error message as same as above. the current operaion user is still jenkins not root.
I modify the config file and input some error code intentionally, and the jenkins can be restart successfuly! this is my config file(the ,,,,, and ---- is just for test):

```
# pulled in from the init script; makes things easier.
NAME=jenkins

# arguments to pass to java

# Allow graphs etc. to work even when an X server is present
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"

#JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx256m"

# make jenkins listen on IPv4 address
#JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME/$NAME.pid

# user and group to be invoked as (default to jenkins)
#JENKINS_USER=$NAME 
#JENKINS_USER=$NAME
JENKINS_USER=root
JENKINS_GROUP=root

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
------------------------------------------------------------

# location of the jenkins war file
JENKINS_WAR=/usr/share/java/$NAME.war

# jenkins home location
JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/$NAME
```

My jenkins version is  2.346.2. so my question is:

1. how can I use jenkins user to run "supservisorctl restart xxxxx"? I preferd jenkins user rather than root.
2. Is this "/etc/defualt/jenkins" the jenkins config file? how to change running user to root?
   Could anyone help me please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I have found the config here: /usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service
I changed User=root Group=root and then systemctl restart jenkins.
It works well!